# What type of extension for VS (and how) to make, to generate C# or C++ code from some text [more so a model]?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I am new to Visual Studio Extensibility and want to make an addin/extension which shall do the following:

1. It should read all the files with a specific file extension (assume "*.ump").
2. It should process the text/code/whatever in the files.
3. It should create new Class/Code file with some code in it. [The code will be produced in step 2, just need to know how to do it?]

Yet, I have been racking my brains through extensibility, saw the single file generators .... and addins which go through ProjectItems and can detect the file extension,
BUT I HAVE NOT BEEN ABLE TO FIND a complete tutorial, guide or explanation as to how or what to do!!

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't want to read all files with a specific file extension in Visual C++ project nor standard Visual C# project. You may do that with hand-made MSBuild project (included in the solution).
2. In Visual C++ projects, there is a way to define custom tools. They are run as separate processes, so you can implement them in anything you want. Studio will ask you whether you want to define a tool (they are defined in special xml files; studio has dialog for editing them) when you add a file with extension unknown to it. In Visual C# projects, just manually write a MSBuild tasks and insert them into the project.
3. Do whatever you want. IIRC the generated files will have to be included in the project though. Well, for MSBuild, just tweak the project to your heart's desire, but in Visual C++ they have to.
4. You can combine MSBuild (csproj,vbproj) and VisualC++ projects in a single solution, so I recommend using separate.
5. If you ever find out you need to compile for different target where you can't use Visual Studio, you'll be glad that you have stand-alone tool you were just calling from Studio and not something that embeds in it.

Comment: Thanx for the effort :)
But, just to be clear, this tool being developed is not for my sole personal use, but will be distributed. (If and when it reaches Production!)
It is being developer for http://cruise.site.uottawa.ca/umple/
and you can check what is already happening with it in Eclipse and I need similar functionality.